# Agrep - dont modify character class

Tags: r, regex

I have a pattern "[^a-z]xxx yyy[^a-z]" that I need to match. I can accept an approximate match in the "xxx yyy" part of the pattern but need the character class to be unchanged.

The above pattern finds a match in strings like "skxxx yyyaa".

I have tried using "<[^a-z]>xxx yyy<[^a-z]>" where the <> metacharacters dont allow for a change but I think it ignores the metcharacters inside <>.

the code is :

```
agrep( "[^a-z]xxx yyy[^a-z]","skxxx yyyaa",max.distance=2,fixed=FALSE,ignore.case=TRUE)
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: I need to match "[^a-z]xxx yyy[^a-z]" approximately in a string with a L distance of 2. But I dont want the character class  [^a-z] to be ignored in the final match.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand.  Can you provide more than a single positive and at least one negative example of a match as well as the output you're hoping to see.  `agrep` returns the index of the match within a vector or the actual value of the match if you set `value=TRUE`

Comment: I dont want agrep( "[^a-z]xxx yyy[^a-z]","skxxx yyyaa",max.distance=2,fixed=FALSE,ignore.case=TRUE) to return a positive match as I dont want a character before or after "xxx yyy" but I am fine with "xxx yyy" matching "dd-xxx yyz assa" not with "ddxxx yyyaa"

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following condition, which checks that the distance comes from the "xxx yyy" piece and not from the surrounding [^a-z].

```
adist("[^a-z]xxx yyy[^a-z]","sk-xxx yyz-aa",fixed=FALSE,ignore.case=TRUE) == 
  adist( "xxx yyy","sk-xxx yyz-aa",fixed=FALSE,ignore.case=TRUE)

> TRUE

adist("[^a-z]xxx yyy[^a-z]","sk-xxx yyzaa",fixed=FALSE,ignore.case=TRUE) == 
  adist( "xxx yyy","sk-xxx yyzaa",fixed=FALSE,ignore.case=TRUE)

> FALSE
```